# Error: Only one model should be specified in tuneGrid with no resampling

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, r-caret, naivebayes

Following is the code:

```
prior_p <- rep(1/520,520)

train_control = trainControl(method= "none")

grid = expand.grid(smooth = "none", prior = prior_p)

model2 <- train(x = training_37_final4[,1:4], y =

training_37_final4$Group.ID, method = "manb", tuneGrid=grid, trControl = train_control)
```

This gives

> Error: Only one model should be specified in tuneGrid with no resampling.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: do you have 520 classes? Try setting prior_p  = 1/520. The error is indicative of the fact the specified grid has a lot of rows while method for evaluation of the hyper parameters was not specified. Even if you did specify for instance `number = 10` for 10 - fold CV in `trainControl` function, it would evaluate 520 models which would be the same since each row in your grid is the same.

Comment: Yes, there are 520 classes. I am not sure what you mean by that. For each class I am specifying equal probability.

Comment: Did you try to run the model with `prior_p = 1/520, grid = expand.grid(smooth = "none", prior = prior_p)`, does it work? What error do you get?

Comment: I get the following error: Error: smooth >= 0 is not TRUE

Comment: Try running `train` without specifying tuneGrid, after the model is made, check the parameters for prior and smooth.

Comment: It runs fine without tuneGrid. I've got the output for the same, but in my case to improve precision I need to give prior probabilities which is not getting resolved at all. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is due to the fact that you are proposing several parameters for the parameter `prior_p`, but still using "none" as the method for train control, which makes caret not know which of the values is the best. So in order for that error to go away you should just change the trainControl() to some value other than `none`.